# What is the difference between String. and String.this. ?

Tags: java, methods, syntax, static, this

I'll get straight to the point. 
Im still learning a bit of syntax and want to know what the difference between this code is

CODE A:

```
 public class Buttonz extends JButton{

        public Buttonz(){
            setText(new String(String.valueOf(i)));
        }

    }
```

Please ignore the fact that `i` is undeclared, that is not where I am lost.

CODE B:

```
public class Buttonz extends JButton{

    public Buttonz(){
        setText(new String(String.this.charAt(i)));
    }

}
```

What I don't yet understand is what the difference is in typing `String.this` and `String.`

I was under the assumption that when I use the dot operator on a class I am accessing it's static methods(and/or variables if they're not hidden).

I have studied this a little bit and have concluded that when using `String.` I am accessing `String` static methods.. but when using `String.this.` I'm accessing the methods that my class `Buttonz` is extending.

Is this correct?

I apologize if I am right and are wasting time. I need to be sure to move on. Thank you.

Comment: Please post code that compiles. None of the examples compile, and it's thus silly to comment on them.

Comment: I am not sure if String.this is even correct.

Answer (score 0):

`String.this` is the "qualified `this`" syntax. It is used to refer to either `this`, if the current class is `String` (which it is not in this case), or if this is a local or anonymous class (a type of inner class), the `this` of an enclosing class named `String` that contains this class. You have not showed us if this class is inside another class; I doubt that is the case. But even if it is, the enclosing class named `String` would not be `java.lang.String`, it must be some other class named `String`, since you cannot add code into existing classes. And then, I highly doubt it would have a method named `charAt()` which returns something which can be passed to `new String()`. So in conclusion, this is not real code.